# Регулярка для валидных телеграм каналов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь выбрать валидные ссылки на телеграм каналы.
Есть массив строк вида :

https://t.me/group1
https://t.me/group2
https://t.me/botgroup1
https://t.me/groupbot
https://t.me/group_bot
https://t.me/joinchat/xR7tqA43Dg
https://www.google.com/en/blabla

Из них подходят первые 3.
Нужно выбрать в которых не присутствует joinchat и bot на конце.

Такой регуляркой выбирает тг-каналы, исключая вхождение joinchat.

```
/t.me\/(?!.*?(?:joinchat))([a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,32})/g;
```

Но не могу сообразить как сделать исключение bot на конце.

Comment: если сложно за раз, то почему бы сначала не выбрать все что после `t,me/`, а потом не отсечь варианты с `(^joinchat|bot$)` ? разве что вы в блокноте это обрабатываете, Конечно

Comment: Не в блокноте)
на nodejs . там можно прогнать массив и убрать через .endsWith('bot') . Но интересно, можно ли сразу через регулярку, чтобы не делать лишний код.

Comment: хороший код это не короткий, а понятный, простой и эффективный. мудреная регулярка внутри гораздо больше будет работать, чем простые ручные проверки.

Comment: `(?<![^\/])t\.me\/(?!.*?joinchat)(?!.*bot$)[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,32}$`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/b83mjJ/1?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо большое! подходит!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```
(?<![^\/])t\.me\/(?!.*?joinchat)(?!.*bot$)[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,32}$
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/9pbNzK/1).

- `(?!.*?joinchat)` - сразу после текущей позиции в строке не должно быть `joinchat`
- `(?!.*bot$)` - в конце строки не должно быть `bot`.